# How to crowd source open data

Tags: data-request, data.gov, releasing-data, linked-data, metadata

Is there a way to get a list of the **top accessed open data sets by organizations** and the organizations which use them?

Comment: The "title" of your question doesn't read (to me) as if it matches the "body." It might help to read them over again and see if you can clarify.  Are you asking about using crowd sourcing to ask organizations which data sets they access?

Answer (score 1):

Here's some of the Top Accessed Open Data sets by organizations:

data.gov Visitor Metrics
https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/data-gov-visitor-metrics

data.gov Search for Popular Datasets
http://catalog.data.gov/dataset?q=&sort=views_recent+desc&ext_location=&ext_bbox=&ext_prev_extent=-183.515625%2C-30.751277776257812%2C-17.578125%2C72.81607371878991

Top Ten Datasets on data.gov (2012)
http://gcn.com/articles/2012/08/24/top-10-datasets-on-data-gov.aspx

You can search data.gov for their most popular datasets:
http://catalog.data.gov/dataset?q=&sort=views_recent+desc&ext_location=&ext_bbox=&ext_prev_extent=-142.03125%2C8.754794702435605%2C-59.0625%2C61.77312286453148

Most Popular Open Datasets from Socrata-powered portals
http://www.opendatanetwork.com/popular-open-datasets

Top Open Data Datasets - Socrata
http://www.socrata.com/top-open-data-datasets/

Top US Cities Open Data Datasets - Socrata
http://www.socrata.com/top-open-data-datasets/us-cities/

Top US Counties Open Data Datasets - Socrata
http://www.socrata.com/top-open-data-datasets/us-counties/

Top US States Open Data Datasets - Socrata
http://www.socrata.com/top-open-data-datasets/us-states/